# Read multiple incoming sms's in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, sms

I have code

```
            DatagramConnection _dc =(DatagramConnection)Connector.open("sms://");         
            Datagram d = _dc.newDatagram(_dc.getMaximumLength());               
            _dc.receive(d); //Receive the sms
            byte[] bytes = d.getData();
            String address = d.getAddress(); //The address of the sms is put on a string.
            String msg = new String(bytes);
```

Does the above code listen for incoming SMS's on a continuous basis, or does it just listen for 1 sms?
If it just listens for 1 SMS can you please provide me with code to listen for SMS's on a continuous basis.

Comment: If you want to listen all the incoming messages, start a thread that listens the messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you please provide me so code on how to do tht?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reads only a single SMS. If you need to read every SMS delivered, you need a loop like this one posted in [the official knowledge base article](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-listen-for-SMS-messages/ta-p/445062):

```
        DatagramConnection _dc = (DatagramConnection)Connector.open("sms://");
        for(;;) {
               Datagram d = _dc.newDatagram(_dc.getMaximumLength());
               _dc.receive(d);
               byte[] bytes = d.getData();
               String address = d.getAddress();
               String msg = new String(bytes);
               System.out.println( "Received SMS text from " + address + " : " + msg);
         }
```

Now a question arises: Is the BB OS delivering SMSs to listening apps in a serial way? If it were (I think so but never tested to that extent), then all you need to do is to forward the message as quickly as possible to a consumer (otherwise you would be hogging the connection listener thread during the SMS processing).